# Do IBM Bluemix and Azure provide equal support to API Blueprint and OpenAPI? To describe APIs

Tags: api, azure, ibm-cloud, openapi, apiblueprint

I could use some help deciding which API Description Language to use for the APIs our team has deployed on IBM Cloud and possibly Azure in the future.

We have been using API Blueprint informally, but when registering the APIs on Bluemix I noticed it (and Azure) have already OpenAPI integrated. However, I don't know if the same is true for API Blueprint. I have been trying to find something that can help decide which way to go, but I haven't found much, other than the Blueprint and the Swagger websites themselves.

I'd like to know if both are interchangeable in the Bluemix and Azure environments, or if there are differences what are they, so I can make a list of pros and cons. Given that we already have progressed with API Blueprint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alo,

Note: I am a beginner when it comes to Azure.

Open API Specification(OAS) has been supported by both IBM and Microsoft for a couple of years or more now. So OAS is a safe bet when you are working with IBM Cloud and Azure. The APIc product (on-premises or its Cloud offering) supports OAS and has supported swagger (which has evolved into OAS) right since its early days.

APIc does not support API Blueprint (you can't import an API Blueprint file into APIc).

From Azure docs, I can't see any reference to APIBlueprint to drive me towards the inference that you can't import API Blueprint defined resources.

I can see reference to swagger/OAS [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-faq) but not to API Blueprint in the context of importing API definitions.